# problem on a function being identically zero

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f:[0,\pi] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(0)=0$.

If $$
\int_0^\pi f(t)\cos nt\, dt = 0
$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0 \}$,  is $f$ identically zero?

Comment: There are answers on very different levels to this question (for example, knowledge about orthonormal bases in Hilbert spaces would make the problem very simple). Some more info on the background and the context where you face the problem would be helpful.

Comment: Please give the answer keeping in mind real analysis.I dont know much about HILBERT SPACES

Comment: Ok, then prove that if you have a continuous function on a finite interval like [a,b], then it exists a sequence of trigonometrical polynomials (power of x becomes cos(kx)) that uniformely converges with f as its limit. It should help you

Comment: how to find a sequence of trigonometrical polynomials can u please give some hints.Thanks in advance

Comment: Is $f(0)=0$ necessary for the question? If we leave that condition out, don't we still get that $f(0)=0$ anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $f$ is continuous on $[0,\pi]$ with $\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\cos nx\,dx=0$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$.

Define a new function $f_{e}$ by first extending $f$ to a even function on $[-\pi,\pi]$, and then by extending periodically to all of $\mathbb{R}$ with period $2\pi$. This new function is continuous everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$ with period $2\pi$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
       \int_{0}^{2\pi}f_{e}(x)\cos nx\,dx
          & = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f_{e}(x)\cos nx\,dx \\
          & = 2\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\cos nx\,dx = 0,\;\;\; n=0,1,2,3,\cdots\;.
\end{align}
$$
And, because $f_{e}$ is even and periodic with period $2\pi$,
$$
        \int_{0}^{2\pi}f_{e}(x)\sin nx \;dx =\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f_{e}(x)\sin nx\,dx = 0,\;\;\; n =1,2,3,\cdots\;.
$$
Therefore, the ordinary Fourier series for $f_{e}$ on $[0,2\pi]$ is now seen to be $0$. I'm assuming you have a theorem that covers this case of the ordinary Fourier series. However, if you only have theorem for differentiable functions, read on ...

**Added because of remark:** If you only have a theorem dealing with continuously differentiable functions, then let $g(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f_{e}(t)\,dx$. Notice that $g$ is continuously differentiable, $g'=f_{e}$, and $g(0)=g(2\pi)=0$ because $\int_{0}^{2\pi}f_{e}(t)\,dt=0$. The Fourier series for $g$ has only a constant term because
$$
\begin{align}
        \int_{0}^{2\pi}g(x)\cos(nx)\,dx & = \left.g(x)\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}\right|_{0}^{2\pi}-\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{2\pi}g'(x)\sin(nx)\,dx \\
         & = -\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f_{e}(x)\sin(nx) = 0,\;\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots, \\
   \int_{0}^{2\pi}g(x)\sin(nx)\,dx & = -\left.g(x)\frac{\cos(nx)}{n}\right|_{0}^{2\pi}+\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{2\pi}g'(x)\cos(nx)\,dx \\
         & = \frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f_{e}(x)\cos(nx) = 0,\;\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots,\\
\end{align}
$$
We are guaranteed that the Fourier series for $g$ converges pointwise everywhere to $g$ and, therefore, $g$ is identically constant. So, $f_{e}=g'$ is identically $0$.

Comment: The problem as stated begs for a Fourier solution like this. But how would you rigorously justify convergence of the series? The standard 'textbook proof' assumes $f(x)$ to be piecewise $C^1$. The next one can try is the Dirichlet–Dini Criterion, but this requires $f(x)$ to be Hölder continuous...

Comment: @Winther : I added an extra argument for you if you don't have the theorem about Fejer means, but only convergence for differentiable functions.

Comment: Very nice solution!

Comment: @Winther : Thanks for the input to make this a nicer solution!

Answer (score 10):

**The Fejér Kernel**

The[Fejér Kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel) is defined as
$$
\begin{align}
F_n(x)
&=\frac1{2\pi}\sum_{|k|\lt n}\left(1-\frac{|k|}{n}\right)\cos(kx)\tag{1}\\
&=\frac{\sin^2(nx/2)}{2\pi n\sin^2(x/2)}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Formula $(1)$ guarantees that
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi F_n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=1\tag{3}
$$
and formula $(2)$ says that
$$
F_n(x)\ge0\tag{4}
$$
For $x\in[0,\pi]$, $\sin(x/2)\ge\dfrac{x}\pi$. Therefore, if $x\in\left.\left[-\pi,\pi\vphantom{n^{1/3}}\right]\middle\backslash\left[-n^{-1/3},n^{-1/3}\right]\right.$, $(2)$ says
$$
F_n(x)\le\frac{\pi}2n^{-1/3}\tag{5}
$$
Furthermore, $(3)$, $(4)$, and $(5)$ imply that
$$
\int_{-n^{-1/3}}^{n^{-1/3}}F_n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\ge1-\pi^2n^{-1/3}\tag{6}
$$

---

**Two Kernels Make A General (Answer)**

Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[0,\pi]$ and for all $k\ge0$,
$$
\int_0^\pi f(x)\cos(kx)\,\mathrm{d}x=0\tag{7}
$$
Since $f$ is continuous on a compact set, it must be bounded; say $|f(x)|\le M$.
Suppose for some $x_0\in(0,\pi)$, $f(x_0)\ne0$. Since $f$ is continuous, there must be a $\delta\gt0$ so that if $|x-x_0|\le\delta$, $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\le |f(x_0)|/2$.

We can assume that $\delta\le\min(x_0,\pi-x_0)$ so that $[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]\subset[0,\pi]$.

Consider
$$
F_n(x+x_0)+F_n(x-x_0)
=\frac1{2\pi}\sum_{|k|\lt n}\left(1-\frac{|k|}{n}\right)2\cos(kx)\cos(kx_0)\tag{8}
$$
Equations $(7)$ and $(8)$ imply that for all $n\gt0$
$$
\int_0^\pi f(x)\big[F_n(x+x_0)+F_n(x-x_0)\big]\,\mathrm{d}x=0\tag{9}
$$
Choose any $n\ge\delta^{-3}$, then $(5)$ says
$$
\left|\int_0^\pi f(x)F(x+x_0)\,\mathrm{d}x\right|
\le\frac{\pi^2}2Mn^{-1/3}\tag{10}
$$
and
$$
\left|\int_{[0,\pi]\setminus[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]}f(x)F_n(x-x_0)\,\mathrm{d}x\right|
\le\frac{\pi^2}2Mn^{-1/3}\tag{11}
$$
Now $(6)$ implies
$$
\left|\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}f(x)F_n(x-x_0)\,\mathrm{d}x\right|
\ge\left|\frac{f(x_0)}{2}\right|(1-\pi^2n^{-1/3})\tag{12}
$$
However, $(9)$, $(10)$, $(11)$, and $(12)$ imply that for all $n\ge\delta^{-3}$,
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\left|\int_0^\pi f(x)\big[F_n(x+x_0)+F_n(x-x_0)\big]\,\mathrm{d}x\right|\\
&\ge\left|\frac{f(x_0)}{2}\right|-\pi^2n^{-1/3}\left[\left|\frac{f(x_0)}{2}\right|+M\right]\tag{13}
\end{align}
$$
Inequality $(13)$ says that for all $n\gt\max\left(\pi^6,\delta^{-1/3}\right)$,
$$
|f(x_0)|\le M\frac{2\pi^2}{n^{1/3}-\pi^2}\tag{14}
$$
Inequality $(14)$ can only be true if $f(x_0)=0$. Thus, our assumption that $f(x_0)\ne0$ must be false and so $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[0,\pi]$.